# laravel - custom search not working, multiple fields

Tags: php, laravel, search

i am trying to create search for my dashbord where have 4 field,

so i can search one by one or both at the same time name, age, location, phone, i wrote a code but its not working

```
    $q = Model::query();

  if (Input::has('name'))
  {
    $q->where('name',Input::get('name'));
  }

  if (Input::has('age'))
  {
    $q->where('age',Input::get('age'));
  }

  if (Input::has('location'))
  {
    $q->where('location', Input::get('location'));
  }

  if (Input::has('phone'))
  {
    $q->where('phone', Input::get('phone'));
  }
```

Getting empty output:

```
[]
```

Comment: Maybe you should include the whole code. This is output of what? What's your Laravel version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 $q = Model::select('id','name','age'); //What ever field you need, This will create model instance

  if (Input::has('name') && !empty(Input::get('name'))
  {
    $q->where('name',Input::get('name'));
  }

  if (Input::has('age') && !empty(Input::get('age'))
  {
    $q->where('age',Input::get('age'));
  }

  if (Input::has('location') && !empty(Input::get('location'))
  {
    $q->where('location', Input::get('location'));
  }

  if (Input::has('phone') && !empty(Input::get('phone'))
  {
    $q->where('phone', Input::get('phone'));
  }
$result = $q->get()->toArray(); 
print_r($result);
```

This should give you what you are looking for

Comment: `why toArray()`?

Comment: `toArray()` is to get response in array format. If you dont give that you will get response as an object.

Comment: user774742 i tried your code its working but problem only first field is working when i leave first two fields empty or leave just first empty getting this error Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
[]

Comment: Dont use array, And i made a mistake before . I forgot to add `&&` in the condition please check on that one